# Photo upload problem from my camera (Nikon d3200) to my PC (Windows 8.1)

Tags: nikon, windows, usb

I'm using a Nikon d3200 camera, and before updating to Windows 8.1, I could upload my photos using USB to my computer which ran Windows 7 at the time. Currently my PC does not recognize the   camera. Is there a solution for it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried going into Windows Update directly, telling it to look for updates, and install any driver updates? Depending on your windows update settings, driver updates and other non-critical OS updates will not get installed automatically, which might leave you lacking required drivers and services to fully support existing hardware. That said, you should also check for any updated Nikon camera software, and install that as well, as camera drivers usually come from the brand itself. Windows MAY offer their own driver only as a convenience.

Comment: @jrista, what I finally did was buying a cheap USB SD card reader and read the photos directly from it. I didn't bother to investigate connecting the camera directly anymore. Thanks for comments anyway.

Comment: That's the best solution. I actually use a USB 3.0 card reader myself for maximum performance...seems to work a lot better than the camera.

Comment: i had same issues but it worked on the usb 3.0 not the 2.0

Comment: The card reader is a better idea as it also avoids battery drain on the camera just to copy the files.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove the SD card and use a separate card reader. Does the NX software from Nikon not recognize that your camera is hooked up? The NX software can transfer photos too.

Comment: Where can I download NX software for Windows 8.1?

Comment: I don't know, have you tried Nikon's website?

Answer (score 0):

Log on to Windows 8 computer with the *administrator account*.
Make sure that the computer is connected with an active Internet connection.

1. Click `Desktop` tile from the `Start screen` to go to the desktop window.
2. Once on the desktop screen, hover mouse to the bottom right corner of the window.
3. From the displayed options, click `Settings`.
4. On the Settings pane, click `Control Panel`.
5. On the opened Control Panel window, click `Hardware and Sound`.
6. On Hardware and Sound window, click `Device Manager` under `Devices and Printers` category from the right pane.
7. On Device Manager window, expand the `Universal Serial Bus controllers` category.
8. Once expanded, right-click the USB controller that is to be updated.
9. From the context menu that appears, click `Update Driver Software...` to update the driver of the selected USB controller.

or

9. From the context menu that appears, click `Uninstall` *(make sure the camera is unplugged)*
10.Restart the computer, plug the camera in and wait for `Windows` to automatically install the drivers.

Source: [What Do I Do If My USB Device Is Not Recognized by Windows 8?](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1655077/usb-device-recognized-windows.html)

Comment: The problem is not with my USB drivers. I tried that before and they are ll up to date. My camera is not recognized though.

Comment: Have you tried using it on a different computer? Either `Windows 8` or at least `Windows 7` or other OS to see if it works?